# How to change the Open Scene Graph plugins directory at runtime (startup)

Tags: c++, plugins, openscenegraph

How to change the Open Scene Graph plugins directory at runtime (startup)?
Currently it points to

> osgPlugins-<version number>

but I want to set it to just

> osgplugins

instead of including the version number. Is it possible to change this setting in code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but according to their FAQ this [isn't necessary when running the INSTALL target](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/PlatformSpecifics/VisualStudio#Importantnoteaboutplugins).